# Using An Array Created In a loop again in another loop with Same Value

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

```
    double[] IndividualAccumulatesArray; 

    for (int i=1;i<=Employees;i++)
    {
        IndividualAccumulatesArray = new double[i];

        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.print("What is the Accumulated Earning's for Employee #"+i+"?   $");
        IndividualAccumulatesArray[i] = reader.nextDouble();
```

so I Created the IndividualAcculates array in the for loop however I want to maintain the value of each array so it can be used in another for loop

```
while(Confirm.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
    {
        for (int i=1;i<=Employees;i++)
        { 
            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.print("How Much Dose Employee #"+i+" Get This Pay Period?   $");
            PayCheck = reader.nextDouble();

            if (IndividualAccumulatesArray[i]>=7000)
            {
```

because it says The Variable `IndividualAccumulatesArray` may not have been initialized for the second for loop

Answer (score 2):

If are going to create a dynamic array where you don't know the initial size.

Use `ArrayList` instead

The problem right now, is you didn't initialize the array before you went into the for loop. Which means it might never be initialized.

If the size of the array needs to be the number of Employees.

```
  double[] IndividualAccumulatesArray = new double[Employees]; 

  for (int i=1;i<=Employees;i++)
  {  
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.print("What is the Accumulated Earning's for Employee #"+i+"?   $");
    IndividualAccumulatesArray[i] = reader.nextDouble();
```

Comment: I would initialize it before the loop however, i is declared in the loop so I can't use i if I initialize it before the loop since i changes with the loop and I want to keep a different value for each i because essentially i identifies the individual employee, and I want to keep the same value for each array item throughout the program.

Comment: @Brendanten Everytime you call `IndividualAccumulatesArray = new double[i]` you are creating a new array of size i, which means you overwrite anything your previously did.

Answer (score 0):

You only declare the variable but don;t initialize the array,just initialize it with Employees as below :

```
double[] IndividualAccumulatesArray = new double[Employees];
```